# Salutation for a letter of recommendation to be uploaded to mathjobs

Tags: recommendation-letter, application

What is a standard opening salutation for a letter of recommendation to be posted on mathjobs?

One possibility might be, "Dear hiring committee", or "Dear search committee".

Comment: I always start my reference letters with “Dear committee members”.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most of my math recommendation letters do not have an opening salutation.  They have the date at the top right, and the first sentence orients the reader with something like "I write to recommend Dr. X to you for..." If I recall correctly, this is fairly typical for such letters.  I am more confident in saying **it doesn't matter**: in general, the format for these letters is all over the place, and no one cares.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't matter. I usually use "Dear Colleagues" but I've also used other salutations without feeling any need to worry about them.

Answer (score 12):

There is the widely used

> To whom it may concern:

and also

> Dear Sir/Madam:

Comment: +1 "To Whom It May Concern" still works. Some people might think it is too old fashioned but I have been using it everywhere with no problems.